# How with sharpziplib get a zip file in memorystream or byte array format and unpack it

Tags: c#, compression, sharpziplib

I have an app that downloads from ftp and gets the format in memorystream or byte array-it gets the zip file ALREADY ZIPPED ,how can i use sharpziplib with this input to unpack that content to a specific place on my harddrive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the raw data in a MemoryStream and then pass this to the zip library instead of a FileStream.